# Spring Web +Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

Could somebody please clear me about below things.

1) Implementing the jwt does that mean remove session from out application i.e from Spring application  & if yes how can I remove complete session from spring app.

2) If I make `<http create-session="stateless">` will this line will not allow Spring application to create the session?

applicationContexx.xml

```
<import resource="classpath*:Spring-Securtiy.xml" />
<bean name="restClient" class="com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client" factory-method="create" />
```

Spring-Securtiy.xml

```
<http entry-point-ref="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint" create-session="stateless" >
```